# How to use canvas to change opacity of a context's arc?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I've been able to draw images using a background image source and change the opacity of the background image to 25% like so...

```
var context = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext('2d');
context.globalAlpha=.25;                

var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);             
}                           
img.src = 'pie_crust.png';
```

And I've been able to draw single arcs...

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var centerX = canvas.width / 2;
var centerY = canvas.height / 2;
var radius = 100;
var startingAngle = 30 * Math.PI/180;
var endingAngle = 60 * Math.PI/180;
var counterclockwise = true;

context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, startingAngle, endingAngle, counterclockwise);
context.lineWidth = 20;
context.strokeStyle = "black"; // line color
context.stroke();
```

However I haven't been able to change the opacity of a context's arc.  For example I have a pie crust (pie_crust.png).

[image]

I would like for the user to specify two sets of start and end angles.  Let's say the first set is (30, 60) and the second set is (135, 180) and counterclockwise is set to true.  I would like those two arcs to have an opacity of 25% and the left over pie crust to have an opacity of 0% so that the resulting canvas would look like this:

[image]

How can I use canvas to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to just draw image using pie-formed [clipping paths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Compositing#Clipping_paths), like this:

```
context.beginPath();
context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, Math.PI/6, Math.PI/3, true);
context.moveTo(centerX, centerY);
context.closePath();
context.clip();
```

Comment: Can you give an example with a loaded image?  I understand the concept of drawing arcs, but I can't get the correct syntax using a background image like `context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);`

Comment: I've provided a link to article, there's an example in it.

Comment: I looked at the article.  However  I need to change the opacity of two arcs of the pie crust to 25% and the leftover arcs to 0%.  The example merely clips the outside of a square to form a circle which is unrelated to what I need help with.  The example doesn't include a source image, which is also a part I'm struggling with.

Comment: Drawing something with opacity 0% is the same as not drawing that at all.
Example demonstrates clipping techinque. It can be used for any clipping path (shape): square, circle, arc...
What do you need image for in that example? You know how to draw them on canvas, code in your answer does it well.